# How do I know if a function has x roots on x-axis?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization

I am currently studying Newton Raphson Method. Now I am kind of having a question that how I know if the function ever has a x-root or roots on x-axis?

Please let me hear your advice.
I am sorry if I have placed my question in the wrong place.

Thank you.

Comment: Why did you tag this question by [tag:physics], [tag:mathematical-physics], [tag:differential-topology]... ?

Answer (score 1):

With Newton-Raphson alone, there really is no way to guarantee a solution is found. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Failure_analysis) has a decent article about some of the failures of the method.

However, the best work around is to a do a grid search on bounds that your function is continuous. This will give you a good ballpark as to where zeros will be (between a positive and negative find). And then you can use this to perform Newton-Raphson to quadratically converge to the zero.

Comment: Maybe this is a new question, I am just wondering in what case Newton-Raphson is really used?

Comment: The case where you believe there to be a root in the area and you have a somewhat decent guess for it's location. So if you suspect there is a root between x=1 and x=2, you use Newton-Raphson to zero in on (hehe pun) the zero by starting N-R at x=1.5 or something. Also, you have to know the bound to within the "niceness" of the function. If it crosses the axis 11 times between x=1 and x=2, only knowing you have a root between x=1 and x=2 won't suffice, but if you only thin that it crosses once between x=1 and x=2 and maybe once between x=10 and x=11, you use it twice to get good precision.

Answer (score 0):

Bolzano's theorem is an useful tool for determining whether a continuous function has atleast one root or not: if a function f(x) over an interval [a,b] has a negative sign at point c, and a positive sign at point d, there exist such x that f(x) = 0, and the x is on the interval ]c,d[. [Intermediate value theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%27s_theorem)

Extensive usage of derivates can also help you: if a function has a maxima or a minima on point x, f'(x)=0. You can then analyze the neighbourhood of the function. If the function is positive,increasing and monotonic on the right side of a minima, there is no roots. Same for negative, decreasing and monotonic.

I hope that this will help.

Comment: I am just wondering why we need to know N-R? Is this method ever used in any industries out there>

Comment: I would guess that analyzing functions in a real working enviroment is done by different computer algebra systems, such as Mathematica or Microsoft Mathematics, which can easily solve functions analytically and numerically. I'm guessing that mathematics interest you, so I'll ask a rhetorical question: why we need to know a certain method, if a computer can use it better than we do? We must know how our enviroment works, so we need to know what the method does. In this case, we need to know N-R because of its historical importance - today there are better methods for numerical solving.